# Does docker pull image in Powershell install on Windows system as well

Tags: docker

I executed the, "docker pull nginx" in Windows Powershell.

On pulling it downloads an image which is in a few MB's

I have Windows 10 pro.

Then i ran nginx as below,
"docker run --name mynginx1 -P -d nginx"

Does the pull command also install nginx on my Windows machine as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the `docker pull` command doesn't install anything, it just downloads the docker image locally. After the pull there's no container running on the host (which is actually a VM in Windows - slightly different if you're using docker desktop or docker-machine, but I won't get into the weeds here). The `docker run` command is what actually runs a container in the docker host.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ryan